# How to connect to the active session of mainframe from Python

Tags: python, win32com, mainframe

How to connect to the active session in mainframe from Python -

```py
import win32com.client

passport = win32com.client.Dispatch("PASSPORT.Session")

session = passport.ActiveSession
if session.connected():
    print("Session active")
else:
    print("Session not active")
```

It is giving a DDL file missing error when activating the .zws file, and when the session is not active it's giving the message, `"Session not active"`.

Can someone please help?

I am using Python3.8 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered a possible solution -
we can create active session in mainframe using `VBA code`.

**And connect the macro through python code.**